# Caching data while using the bloc pattern

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I want to implement caching in my app such that the data is only loaded once and then every time the page is reloaded, data does not have to be fetched again

The code below is a pages bloc.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:eightoeight/eightoeight.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AlbumBloc {
  DatabaseClient db;

  Stream<List<AudioTrack>> get albums => _albumSubject.stream;

  final _albumSubject = BehaviorSubject<UnmodifiableListView<AudioTrack>>();

  final modeController = StreamController<int>();

  Sink<int> get mode => modeController.sink;

  var _albums = <AudioTrack>[];

  AlbumBloc() {
    create();
  }

  void create() async {
    if (db == null) {
      this.db = new DatabaseClient();
      await this.db.create();
    }

    modeController.add(0);
    modeController.stream.listen(onData);
  }

  void onData(int num) {
    if (num == null) {
      _updateSongs(0).then((_) {
        _albumSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(_albums));
      });
    } else if (num == 1) {
      _updateSongs(1).then((_) {
        _albumSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(_albums));
      });
    } else if (num == 2) {
      _updateSongs(2).then((_) {
        _albumSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(_albums));
      });
    } else {
      _updateSongs(0).then((_) {
        _albumSubject.add(UnmodifiableListView(_albums));
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _updateSongs(int num) async {
    var tracks;
    if (num == 1) {
      tracks = await db.fetchAlbumOrderArtist();
    } else {
      tracks = await db.fetchAlbum();
    }

    _albums = tracks;
  }
}
```

The code above just fetches a list from the database. I want it to fetch from the database only when the app starts and then load data from the cache on subsequent requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a Repository class like `AlbumDataRepository`.
2. Have method like `fetchData` in it.
3. Call that method from your BLoC.
4. In `fetchData()` of that repository class first check if data is available in cache
    a. if data is in cache then fetch it and return.
    b. If data is not in cache fetch from database store it in cache and return that data.

**Note:** in your repository class you should also have a method like `clearCache`. When data is expired call that method and delete all data from cache so that next time you get updated data.